# PowerPivot get the last value recorded for a date

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, powerpivot, microsoft-excel-365, dax

I have a PowerPivot query where I have 3 columns: ID, Date and a Value. Every day is possibly recorded multiple values each on new row. so it looks like:

```
ID  Date        Value
1   1/1/2019    654594
2   1/1/2019    987452
3   1/2/2019    6598
4   1/2/2019    549898
5   1/2/2019    5489785
6   1/3/2019    49456
7   1/3/2019    8994969
8   1/3/2019    1843
```

My goal is to filter the table using a DAX calculation so for every day I can get only the value with the highest ID (in my subsequent Pivot tables).... and I am still only getting the maximal value for that day. Can someone lead me to what I need or tell me straight away how to achieve what I need?
Dates are connected to other table with more date/time control features.

It should result these rows from the table above:

```
ID  Date        Value
2   1/1/2019    987452
5   1/2/2019    5489785
8   1/3/2019    1843
```

... So far I have a measure which is giving me the max ID for each day - but I am not able to pair it to the value column. It looks like this:
Last ID for date filter:

```
=CALCULATE(max(Table[ID]);ALLEXCEPT(DateTable;DateTable[Date]))
```

Thanks for help and/or advices

Comment: Is more information needed?

Comment: In my opinion, you can count the date, if the date count is the max, you can return the value. This is my idea but I don't know if it possible in PowerPivot.